# Chat feed bot for hot questions

Tags: support, chat

There's a Hot Network Questions list and it has an RSS feed which could be used to create a chat feed bot. However, it doesn't allow to filter by site (or at least this functionality is hidden, because [this clearly doesn't work](http://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions?sites=anime), but [some random parameter like this](http://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions?asdfasdfasdf=vbnmvbnmvbm) just shows you the [unmodified page](http://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions)).

Is it possible to have add a chat feed bot for the newly heated questions for a specific site?

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that the HNQ feed [only contains the top 30 HNQs and not all 100](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277719/162011).

Answer (score 1):

The RSS feed for "hot questions" for on our main site is:

https://anime.stackexchange.com/feeds/hot

You don't need to parse or filter from the feed for all network questions. Just use the site specific hot questions feed and change the site url as needed.

Alternatively, you can use a third-party solution like [FeedRinse](http://www.feedrinse.com/) to create a custom filtered feed.

Here is an example of the hot network questions feed with only questions from CodeGolf.SE:

http://www.feedrinse.com/services/rinse/?rinsedurl=d9080bfa77f2f87631f6515a906b6f8c

The filter criteria was simple, look at the `<title>`, if "codegolf.stackexchange.com" is in the title, show it in the feed, otherwise ignore it.

You do things with this like combining it with some service like IF This Then That (IFTTT)'s SMS channel to send you a SMS text alert every time a hot question appears on the list that is from code golf.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the questions there are hot enough to appear in the network-wide list and the sidebar. Maybe these are the hottest on the site, but I'm mostly interested in hotness levels that result in being seen on the whole network. So I suppose filtering the main feed would be an easy way to achieve that.

Comment: You can customize and restructure existing feeds with [IF This Then That (IFTTT)](https://ifttt.com/wtf).

Comment: you know it's not happening